# Mantener compomente React Flow Renderer en memoria aunque no se esté mostrando

Tags: reactjs, optimización, memoria, tree, diagrama-de-flujo

Tengo una aplicación con diferentes pestañas, en una de las cuales se muestra una instancia de React Flow. Sin embargo, actualmente, cada vez que cambio de pestaña y vuelvo a la de React Flow, este se inicializa de nuevo, lo cual provoca que se congele la pantalla durante varios segundos. Además, los cambios que hubiera realizado (crear nodos, conexiones, etc) también desaparecen y vuelve al estado inicial.

Por tanto, me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de "mentener en memoria" el estado del componente para evitar esa reinicialización y conservar los datos previos sin tener que guardarlos en localStorage y luego leerlos en una misma sesión.

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes echarle un ojo a `Redux` es un estado interno global que mantiene en `store` global la información que desees dentro de la aplicación

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido Redux solo me serviría para guardar la información del componente, pero cuando se lo pase, este tendría que inicializarse de nuevo, que es lo que causa el problema